# Magento 2: How to quickly import the color swatches?

Tags: magento2, attributes, color-swatches

I've more than 50k attributes to apply the color swatches, I'd like to know if there are different method more easy or fast than the manual process?

Comment: By default, you can't import swatches, but it's possible with our commercial extension https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html , sample CSV for swatches import https://github.com/firebearstudio/magento2-import-export-sample-files/blob/master/Improved%20Import%20:%20Export%20-%20Sample%20Files/products_swatches_import.csv

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me.

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('../app/bootstrap.php');

// color = data[23]

// add bootstrap
$attrCode = 'color';
$bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();

$app_state = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$formattedAttrOptions = readOptions();
$storeArr = getAllStores( $object_Manager );
addAttrsOptions( $formattedAttrOptions, $object_Manager, $storeArr, $attrCode );

function readOptions() {

$options = $alloptions = array();
$file = 'csv/all_products_2020-03-22.csv';
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$headers = false;

if (empty($handle) === false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if (!$headers) {
            $headers[] = $data;
        } else {
            if(isset($data[23]) && ($data[23] != '')){
            $options[] = trim($data[23]);
          }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$formattedAttrOptions = formatAttrOptions($options);
return $formattedAttrOptions;

}

function formatAttrOptions($alloptions) {

  $uniqueValues = array_unique($alloptions);
  asort($uniqueValues);
  $optionValues = array_values($uniqueValues);
  //echo '<pre>';
  //print_r($optionValues);die();
  return $optionValues;

}




 function getExistingOptions( $object_Manager , $attr ) {

$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attr);
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
$optionsExists = array();

foreach($options as $option) {
    $optionsExists[] = $option['label'];
}
return $optionsExists;

}

function addAttrsOptions( $formattedAttrOptions, $object_Manager, $storeArr, $attrCode) {

$newOptions = $existingOptions = array();
$existingOptions = getExistingOptions( $object_Manager, $attrCode );
$newOptions = cmpOptions( $formattedAttrOptions, $existingOptions );
$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attrCode);
//echo $attrCode.PHP_EOL;die();

if( sizeof($newOptions) > 0 ) {

  $finalAttributeOptions = createOptionsArray($newOptions);
  $data = generateOptions($finalAttributeOptions, 'visual');
  $data = uploadSwatchFileToAttributeFolder( $object_Manager, $data );
  $attribute->addData($data)->save();

}
}

function generateOptions($values, $swatchType = 'visual')
{
      $i = 0;
     foreach($values as $key => $value) {
     $order["option_{$i}"] = $i;
    $optionsStore["option_{$i}"] = array(
        0 => $key, // admin
        1 => $value['label'], // default store view
    );
    $textSwatch["option_{$i}"] = array(
        1 => $value['label'],
    );
    $visualSwatch["option_{$i}"] = $value['url'];
    $delete["option_{$i}"] = '';
    $i++;
}

switch($swatchType)
{
    case 'text':
        return [
            'optiontext' => [
                'order'     => $order,
                'value'     => $optionsStore,
                'delete'    => $delete,
            ],
            'swatchtext' => [
                'value'     => $textSwatch,
            ],
        ];
        break;
    case 'visual':
        return [
            'optionvisual' => [
                'order'     => $order,
                'value'     => $optionsStore,
                'delete'    => $delete,
            ],
            'swatchvisual' => [
                'value'     => $visualSwatch,
            ],
        ];
        break;
    default:
        return [
            'option' => [
                'order'     => $order,
                'value'     => $optionsStore,
                'delete'    => $delete,
            ],
        ];
}
 }

  function uploadSwatchFileToAttributeFolder( $object_Manager, $data ) {

  $filesystem = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');

 // Prepare visual swatches files.
 $mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
$productMediaConfig = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config');
 $tmpMediaPath = $productMediaConfig->getBaseTmpMediaPath();
 $fullTmpMediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($tmpMediaPath);

 $driverFile = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File');
 $driverFile->createDirectory($fullTmpMediaPath);
 $swatchHelper = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media');

 foreach ($data as $key => $attributeOptionsData) {
  if($key == "swatchvisual" ){
      $swatchVisualFiles = isset($attributeOptionsData['value'])? $attributeOptionsData['value'] : [];
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($swatchVisualFiles);die();


      foreach ($swatchVisualFiles as $index => $swatchVisualFile) {
          if(!empty($swatchVisualFile)){
              if(file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'swatches' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile)) {
                  $driverFile->copy(
                  __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'swatches' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile,
                  $fullTmpMediaPath . '/' . $swatchVisualFile
                  );

                  $newFile = $swatchHelper->moveImageFromTmp($swatchVisualFile);
                  if (substr($newFile, 0, 1) == '.') {
                      $newFile = substr($newFile, 1); // Fix generating swatch variations for files beginning with ".".
                  }
                  $swatchHelper->generateSwatchVariations($newFile);
                  $data[$key]['value'][$index] = $newFile;
              } else {
                  $data[$key]['value'][$index] = "";
              }
          }
      }
  }
 }

//echo '<pre>';
//  print_r($data);die();

  return $data;

}


 /*
Create array of options with swatch Images
*/

function createOptionsArray($newOptions) {

 $finalAttributeOptions = array();

 foreach ( $newOptions as $key => $value) {

$swatchFileName = strtolower($value).".png";
$finalAttributeOptions[$value] =  array("label" => $value, "url" => $swatchFileName );

 }
 return $finalAttributeOptions;

 // echo '<pre>';
 // print_r($finalAttributeOptions);

 }

 // Compare with Existing options

  function cmpOptions( $optionsValues, $optionsExists ) {

$newOptions = array_diff( $optionsValues, $optionsExists );
return $newOptions;

}[![enter image description here][1]][1]

 // Get all stores

function getAllStores( $object_Manager ) {
$storeManager = $object_Manager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$stores = $storeManager->getStores();
$storeArray[0] = "All Store Views";

foreach ($stores  as $store) {
    $storeArray[$store->getId()] = $store->getName();
}
return $storeArray;
}
```

Comment: Whats the format of the csv file?